# Compare selected values of two Excel 2013 Powerpivot Slicers in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 pivot tables with powerpivot connection, and I need to propagate selected values from one slicer (connected to table1) to another slicer (connected to table2):

```
Dim sl As Variant
sl = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_V").VisibleSlicerItemsList
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_V1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = sl
```

Works perfectly but calls recalculation of table2 every time.

I just want to avoid redundant calculations by adding this check before my code:

```
if(Slicer_2.SelectedValues = Slicer_1.SelectedValues) then: exit sub
```

plz advice how to comapare them

Answer (score 0):

Here's code I use to work with slicers:

```
Sub SetSlicer(ByVal SlicerName As String, ByVal value As String)
If value = "clear" Then
    'Clearing takes a while to refresh, so only do if slicer is filtered
    If Right(ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).VisibleSlicerItemsList(1), 5) <> "[All]" Then
        ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).ClearManualFilter
    End If
Else
    'Setting a value takes a while on pivots, so only do if slicer is a different value.
    'Note that if more than one value set in slicer, this code could fail to reset a slicer that needs reset. I'll take the chance...
    If ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).VisibleSlicerItemsList(1) <> value Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(value)
        If Err.Number = 5 Then
            MsgBox "Error. Confirm that " & SlicerName & " exists.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End If
End Sub

Function GetSlicer(SlicerName As String, Optional item As Integer = 1) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    GetSlicer = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).VisibleSlicerItemsList(item)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```